# How to get an Interface Member name from Expression<Action<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm looking for a way to get the interface member name of the expression passed into `Client.SendMessage`. Below is what I've attempted, but I get an invalid cast exception.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Operation1(object data);
    void Operation2(object data);
}

public class FooClient<T>
{
    public void SendMessage(Expression<Action<T>> expr)
    {
        // InvalidCastException:
        // Cannot cast 'InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to 'MemberExpression'
        var iMemberName = ((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member.Name;

        Console.WriteLine(iMemberName);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var client = new FooClient<IFoo>();

        // Should write 'Operation1'
        client.SendMessage(x => x.Operation1("Hello, world!"));

        // Should write 'Operation2'
        client.SendMessage(x => x.Operation2("How are you?"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the inner expression is a [`MethodCallExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.aspx) (and not a `MemberExpression`, which represents property or field access expressions), you should cast it appropriately and get the name of the MethodInfo object returned by the [`Method` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.method.aspx).

```
public class FooClient<T>
{
    public void SendMessage(Expression<Action<T>> expr)
    {
        var iMemberName = ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method.Name;

        Console.WriteLine(iMemberName);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Didaxis Sorry, I've added a bit more explanation. Here is a demo: http://ideone.com/LVbL0d